# SQL query within while loop in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm new to php and I try to build my own blog system. Until now everything works fine except for one issue.

I try to show the number of comments for each blog post. But it won't work and I can't figure out why.

Here is the code:

```
include('db URL');

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT post_id, ... cat_name, cat_id FROM posts ORDER BY nse_p_id DESC");
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($post_id, $cat, $cat_id);
```

Now to the HTML part

```
 <div class="media-body span8">
        <?php                   
            while($query->fetch()): 
        ?>

            <div class="blogpostfield">
                <div  class="blogpostinfo">
                    Category <?php echo "<a href='sort.php?cat_id=$cat_id'><b>".$cat."</b></a>"?>
                    with <?php 
                        $comCount = $db->query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE com_post_id = '$post_id'");
                        if($comCount){
                            echo $comCount;
                        }else{
                            echo "ERROR - count unsuccessful";
                        }

                        ?> 
                    comments

                </div>
            </div>      
        <?php endwhile?>
</div>
```

This is just a snipped. Everthing else works fine. 
The problem is imo that the query within the while loop doesn't work. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Andy

Comment: You're echoing a resource instead of a string.

Comment: why not use a direct SQL count

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want the number of rows in your result.

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE com_post_id = '$post_id'");
$comCount = $result->num_rows;
```

You could also just count the number of rows in the query:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comment WHERE com_post_id = '$post_id'");
$comCount = $result->fetch_field;
```